# how to handel Pandas CSV string with double quotes inside

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I'm having problem while processing CSV file like this format :

input.csv file:

```
1,abc,65.0,en-GB,"reverted,Knowledge Alert,ab00998978,1,Y,Y,default,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
2,zolhOgdmpwAQjfaUONdTD7,15.0,en-GB,"New & Dropped Routes,Article,KM100015050,2,N,Y,default,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
3,zolhOgdmpwAQjfaUONdTD7,4.0,en-GB,"New & Dropped Routes,Article,KM100015050,3,N,Y,default,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
```

metadata.csv file

```
tablename,silver_tablename,fileformat,fileformat_historical,silver_overwrite,preprocessing,cdc,bronzeload,silverload,softdelete,harddelete,harddeleteonlykeys,deletecolumn,deletevalue,executionset,readeroptions,autoloaderoptions,autoloaderoptions_historical,enabled,encoding_format,bronze_overwrite,sensitive_data,data_protection
agent,agent,csv,csv,N,Y,N,Y,Y,Y,N,N,OPERATION,D,set1,"{'header': 'true', 'sep': 'chr(1)', 'quoting':'csv.QUOTE_NONE','readerCaseSensitive': 'false'}",,,Y,UTF-8,N,N,N
```

but after running my code all data after double quote going to single column.

My code:

```
import pandas as pd

entity_df = pd.read_csv(entity_control_source_path, header=0, sep=",", quotechar='"', dtype=str)
```

[image: 1]

[image: 2]

Comment: can you add your code to the question please? Thanks! :-)

Comment: in py file 
entity_df = pd.read_csv(entity_control_source_path,
                        header=0, sep=",", quotechar='"', dtype=str)

Answer (score 0):

You can have pandas ignore quoting entirely by passing `quoting=3` to `pd.read_csv()`:

```
df = pd.read_csv('input.csv', quoting=3, header=None)
```

See the [official documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html).

Alternatively, you could clean up your data manually beforehand and read it in as you regularly would.

Comment: 'quoting':'csv.QUOTE_NONE' is already added in metadata.csv file still its not working